# ksh - Reading an unset variable into an array using the read command

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ksh

I have the following ksh script, where $an_unset_var is an unset variable which is being used for the first time:

```
read -A arr <<< "$an_unset_var"
echo ${#an_unset_var}
echo ${#arr[*]}
```

Executing which, I get the following output:

```
0
1
```

Why does reading an unset variable into an array using the read command enter an empty element in the array? Why would this empty element be considered a valid countable element of the array?

Comment: Also asked here: https://superuser.com/questions/1316791/ksh-reading-an-unset-variable-into-an-array-using-the-read-command

Answer (score 0):

You read an empty string into the array.  The array is unset and then it's first element is set to the empty string.

The empty string is a perfectly valid piece of data.  I'm not sure what you were expecting to happen.

The equivalent set of commands would be

```
unset arr
arr[0]=""
```

`arr` is now an array with one element. Its element is the empty string.

Comment: I think part of the question here is why `ksh` behaves differently from `bash` here... On `bash`: `read -a arr <<< ""; echo ${#arr[@]}` returns 0... (And no, I don't really know why...)

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger Huh. I would almost consider that a bug in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment: difference between bash and ksh

```
$ ksh -c 'read -A a <<<""; typeset -p a'
typeset -a a=('')

$ bash -c 'read -a a <<<""; declare -p a'
declare -a a='()'
```